# Need a design pattern for AJAX requests that don't complete before HTML form is submitted

Tags: html, ajax, design-patterns, race-condition

I've done several forms that follow a similar pattern:

- two interdependent form fields, let's say "street address" and "location" (lon/lat).
- when user fills in one field, the other is updated via an ajax call.

  (eg. if the user fills in street address, do a request to a geocode API and put the result in the location field; if the user fills in the location (eg. via a map UI), do a request to a reverse-geocode API and put the result in the address field.
  No problem so far, these are easy to hook up to blur and/or focus change events.)
- The problem occurs if the form is submitted before an ajax call completes. In this case one field will have a correct value and the other will be stale. The handler on the server needs to detect that this has happened and update the stale value. We can't just check for the default value because the user might have changed both fields any number of times.

There are two possible solutions I've thought of, and I don't much like either one. I'd love other suggestions.

**Solution 1.**  Use hidden fields as flags to indicate freshness: set the value to 0 by default, reset it to 0 before the ajax request is sent, and set it to 1 when the response comes back.  On the server side, check these fields and recompute any field whose freshness flag is set to 0.  There is still a potential race condition here but the window is greatly narrowed.  I've used this technique and it works (eg. http://fixcity.org/racks/new/).  It is annoying though, as it requires more code on both client and server and is another possible source of bugs.

**Solution 2.** Use synchronous AJAX calls instead ("SJAX"?).  Not appealing since AJAX here is just a UI convenience, it's not strictly necessary for the application to work, so I'd rather not make things feel slow - then it becomes UI *in*convenience.

**Solution 3.** Always do server-side postprocessing. If it's expensive, use caching to make it cheaper - eg. if the value is *not* stale, that means the client just made the same request via AJAX so we should have populated the cache if needed during the AJAX handler.
This one currently seems the most appealing to me, although it has two limitations:
it can't be used for things that are not safe and idempotent - eg. if the AJAX request was doing a POST; and it can't even be used for this example because we have two interdependent fields and no way to know which is correct and which is stale.

Answer (score 2):

When the user presses submit, have it run a validation function that decides what state the form is in by examining the form fields and the state of the ajax call (set a flag, such as ajaxBusy).

Comment: ok, that sounds like a client-side-only variant of solution 1. On the one hand it's nicer because there's less to do on the server side, on the other hand submission will be blocked until the ajax response comes.

Answer (score 2):

You could enhance your AJAX call to both disable the form submit button and set a global var to to `true` that is checked on form submit~ That way the user **can't** submit the form before AJAX completes. I would add a loading graphic for UI sake.

Answer (score 1):

You should validate what is submitted on server-side anyway. If both fields are related 1-1, then you can designate one of them as "master", and submit it alone, while the other one is calculated server-side.

Comment: Unfortunately there cannot be a "master" in this case: either input alone must be considered sufficient.